# UItableviewcell custom cell not showing details

Tags: ios

Any help please!! I am trying to show title and details, but details do not display(blank).

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }



    NSString * theCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@ to %@ at %@", [flights valueForKey:@"depAirport"],[flights valueForKey:@"destAirport"],[flights valueForKey:@"depTime"]];
    NSLog(@"the %@", theCell);

    // Configure the cell...
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[flights objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"flight_ID"];


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = theCell;


    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be appreciate!!

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: yes. I have a uitableview controller with custom cell, but i didnt add any label there. thanks

Comment: Is the NSLog for `theCell` displaying the correct data?

Comment: yes it has  data on it. I also put a simple string to test, but same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard, your **cell** not become **nil**. That means cell is always returned from dequeue method. So your cell initialization code never get initialized and the style doesn't change to **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle**. Therefore detail text label doesnt exist.

So you have to change the prototype in the storyboard to have the subtitle style.

Comment: you're right!! so silly question!! thanks a lot. I changed style to subtitle and works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

What UITableViewCellStyle are you using? **UITableViewCellStyleDefault** will not work.